# BCP error if last column is empty

Tags: bcp

My bcp app is getting an error if the last column in the datafile is empty.  This causes an error:

```
XX,YY,42,0,2,201501,652,,
```

This doesn't:

```
XX,YY,42,0,2,201501,652,,0
```

Unfortunately I can't specify a zero instead of a null.  The destination table allows null on every column.  The datatype is float (the last three columns are floats in fact).  Here's the format file:

```
8.0
9
1       SQLCHAR       0       10      ","                       1     NOT          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR       0       10      ","                       2     VIOLATING    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       10      ","                       3     COMPANY      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0       2       ","                       4     POLICY       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR       0       2       ","                       5     ON           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR       0       6       ","                       6     INFORMATION  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR       0       25      ","                       7     SECURITY     ""
8       SQLCHAR       0       25      ","                       8     QTY2         ""
9       SQLCHAR       0       25      "\n"                      9     QTY1         ""
```

The error:

```
Row 1, Column 9: Invalid character value for cast specification
```

Comment: Is the last character in your datafile the row terminator?

Comment: It is.  I know for sure because If I replace ',,' with ',,0' at the end of the line, the import works.